# Cake PHP 2.5.2. sessions reading from database

Tags: php, database, session, cakephp

I cannot read values from cake php sessions when set to database, it returns null.

I have set in core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database'
));
```

I have setup a cakephp sessions table , it stores session data in the table.

I try to read it back with

```
$pid = $this->Session->read('Projectid');
```

I write it with

```
  $this->Session->write('Projectid', key($projects) );
```

Any ideas?
It works when using php sessions but not database.

Database sql

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cake_sessions` (
     `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `data` text,
  `expires` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

UPDATE

I found that if i remove a line that writes a list to the session, it can read other variables.Is this a bug?

```
 $projects =   $this->Project->find('list', array('fields' => array('id','name')
$this->Session->write('Projects', $projects); //removing this line i can read
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i was using Japanese in a table but it was not set to UTF-8, this was causing issues with saving sessions to db.

Answer (score 0):

Using CakePHP 2.3  i was experimenting the same issue, was not able to write or read in Session using defaults database config.

Then, i followed this sample, [Custom Handler CakePHP Session](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#creating-a-custom-session-handler), but i has not access to the server in order  to configure php-apc properly, so,  just i removed the apc feature from the sample.

My final code in app/Model/Datasource/Session/CustomSessionHandler.php (ComboSession in the sample)  looks like this.

```
<?php

App::uses('DatabaseSession', 'Model/Datasource/Session');

class CustomSessionHandler extends DatabaseSession implements     CakeSessionHandlerInterface {
    public $cacheKey;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // read data from the session.
    public function read($id) {
        $result = Cache::read($id);
        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        }
        return parent::read($id);
    }

    // write data into the session.
    public function write($id, $data) {
        Cache::write($id, $data);
        return parent::write($id, $data);
    }

    // destroy a session.
    public function destroy($id) {
        Cache::delete($id);
        return parent::destroy($id);
    }

    // removes expired sessions.
    public function gc($expires = null) {
        Cache::gc();
        return parent::gc($expires);
    }
}
```

My app/Config/core.php session config section.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
  'defaults' => 'database',
  'handler' => array(
      'engine' => 'CustomSessionHandler',
      'model'  => 'Session'
   )
));
```

And finally my table creation to store sessions.

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data` text,
  `expires` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

After this steps, now i can read from and write to Session, without any issues, and my sessions are stored in 'sessions' table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i found what the issue actually was see my answer